# Power BI - Filter table by clicking on a card

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

In Power BI, I have a table that contains rows associated with one of five possible categories. I've created three cards that shows the count of rows for category 1, category 2, and the remaining three possible categories.

I would like to filter the table based on the card that I click on. How can I filter visuals by clicking on a card?

[image: Current result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Power BI card as a filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283813/how-to-use-power-bi-card-as-a-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using bookmarks. The following link walks you through how you can create a bookmark and use it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks

You should place buttons over each of the cards (Make sure you turn off the background and borders to make sure they look aesthetically right). Then all you have to do is assign bookmarks to each of the buttons to filter the corresponding data. Hope this helps.

Comment: That was exaclty what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I developed a custom visual called **Slicer Button** that can be used to essentially turn a card into a slicer/filter. The bookmark solution above has some drawbacks, such as affecting other filters, which this custom visual avoids.

Below is a GIF of the visual in use.

[image: Slicer Button Demonstration]

I've included a YouTube video demonstrating how to setup and use the visual and a link to the GitHub repository that hosts it.

**Basic Setup & Use:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x2QoE8M2yA&ab_channel=MattKocak

**GitHub Repository:** https://github.com/mattkocak/powerbi-visuals-slicerbutton

Let me know if you have any questions or comments. I'm happy to clarify anything. I also have a blog post on the topic titled [Turn your cards into slicers with the Slicer Button custom visual](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Turn-your-cards-into-slicers-with-the-Slicer-Button-custom/ba-p/2676449).